# Where I can find all dexterity widgets

Tags: plone, dexterity

Is there a single place where I can find all standard and custom widgets for dexterity field.

Standard widgets can be found at following link

http://developer.plone.org/reference_manuals/external/plone.app.dexterity/reference/widgets.html

BUT, there is no single reference where I can check all possible custom widgets community has developed before I start thinking to develop widget for our user-case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list in the manual is intended to be that single place. Anyone should feel free to contribute to it on github: https://github.com/plone/plone.app.dexterity/blob/master/docs/reference/widgets.rst

Comment: Thanks. I will try to contribute but also ask community to also add if they came across any. Thanks agian David